# Annotations are not allowed here when moving to a separated class

Tags: android

I try to separate my Location finding code from the Main activity, so I moved the entire related code to a different class:
(*I began with Android today and Java is also fairly new to me, so sorry if this is a silly question)

```
public class LocationCode {

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private TextView tv;
    private Button button;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 5;
    public LocationCode (Context context, TextView textView, Button btn) {

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        this.tv = textView;
        this.button = btn;
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    // Update UI with location data
                    Double latDouble = location.getLatitude();
                    String latString = latDouble.toString();
                    Double longtDouble = location.getLongitude();
                    String longtString = longtDouble.toString();
                    tv.setText(latString + " " + longtString);

                }
            }
        };
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults){
            TextView tv1 = this.tv;
            Button button = this.button;
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            //
                        } else {
                            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
                                    null /* Looper */);
                        }

                    } else {
                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                        tv1.setText("Not Granted!");
                        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    return;
                }

                // other 'case' lines to check for other
                // permissions this app might request.
            }
        }

    }   


}
```

From MainActivity I should probably call this code like so:
`LocationCode locationCode = new LocationCode(this, textView, Button);`

But I get the following error on the second `@Override` (The one above `public void onRequestPermissionsResult`). Why is that, and how can I fix it? Or there is a better way to separate this code to make it look more neat in the MainActivity?

Comment: To override some methods the current class must be a child of a super class with that class, so in this case `onRequestPermissionsResult` may not be a method from super class of LocationCode. And its obvious since it does not extend any class.

Comment: Also, you have that annotated `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method inside the constructor. It can't go there, which is what the current error message is telling you.

Comment: `onRequestPermissionsResult` comes from `FragmentActivity` class. In your `LocationCode` you don't extend from FragmentActivity therefore you don't have that method. Also you are missing a parenthesis to close your constructor

Comment: Could you please help me then make my class valid? I tried moving stuff, extending the class but I still get all sorts of errors. An example of working class would be very helpful, thank you guys

Comment: For now, keep the permissions stuff in the `Activity`. That is, move `onRequestPermissionsResult()` back to the `Activity`. It's more work than you'll likely want to do, at this point, to separate that from the `Activity`. (It's also rather clunky, as far as design, and I wouldn't recommend it.) That will take care of the current error.

Comment: But I just wonder how you guys, experienced Java people would separate these codes to make it more organized. It's a mess right now